# What does the zeta squared function converge to

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, riemann-zeta

Define a series: $f(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ where $n$ is a natural number. This series converges to $0$.

Now, consider the series $S(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(i)$. This is the Reimann Zeta function evaluated at $2$ and it converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Now consider the series $R(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n S(i)$. Does this converge to anything? If so, what does it converge to?

And if $R(n)$ diverges, what about $R_k(n)$ where we start with $f(n) = \frac{1}{n^k}$ instead? At what value of $k$ will we get convergence?

---

My attempt:

I managed to establish that

$$R(n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{(n-i+1)}{i^2} = n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2} = n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

With the first two terms, we get an $\infty - \infty$ form which is indeterminate. It seems like the first sum should overpower the second one. This is because the first one is linear is $n$ while the second one is logarithmic. Not sure if this argument is precise enough. And now what about the $k$ for which $R_k(n)$ converges?

Answer (score 4):

Using generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_2(n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(i)=H_n^{(2)}$$
Using the polygamma function
$$R_2(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n S_2(i)=(n+1) H_{n+1}^{(2)}-\psi ^{(0)}(n+2)-\gamma$$

For large values of $n$
$$R_2(n)=\frac{\pi ^2 }{6}n-\log(n)+\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\gamma -1\right)-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{5}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

For the next one
$$S_3(n) = H_n^{(3)}$$
$$R_3(n) =(n+1) H_{n+1}^{(3)}+\psi ^{(1)}(n+2)-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$
$$R_3(n) = \zeta (3)n+\left(\zeta (3)-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your series doesn't exist. This is because the summand approaches $\frac{\pi^2}6$ and not $0$. Same thing for all $k$, the summand of $R_k$ will approach $\zeta(k)>1$.

Comment: I see. This can be rectified by subtracting $\pi^2/6$ from each term.

Comment: @RohitPandey I still highly doubt that it converges though because of how slow it takes for the summand minus $\frac{\pi^2}6$ to become zero.

Comment: Per Claude's answer, it will converge.

Comment: Notice the first term of the asymptotic expansion in Claude’s answer.

Comment: Ah, you're right. But $R_3(n)$ will converge if you subtract $\zeta(3)$ from all the terms. And so will $R_k(n)$ for $k \geq 3$